# Airflow display more than 365 dagrun

Tags: user-interface, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to display more than 365 dagruns on the Airflow task duration diagram. I found where the drop-down list values are defined in the [sources](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/forms.py), but I don't want to fork the whole project just for that. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't be able to change the UI without forking the project, but this is controlled by the `num_runs` query parameter which you can change manually in the URL.

```
http://<host>/admin/airflow/tree?dag_id=<dag_id>&num_runs=500
```

Not great, but if this is just for one DAG that you look at often, then you can just bookmark that.

Depending on what you're looking for, the `Browse -> Task Instances` or `Browse -> DAG Runs` pages might be more appropriate.